# CSS :hover Within an 'absolute' Positioned Element

Tags: css

I've got a friend, mrOverAbsolute, who wants to sit on top of another friend, mrAbsolute. Neither one seems to complain. I've got another friend,  who responds to "mrHover" that wants to use a sprite. mrHover is only happy when the big dogs, mrHover and mrOverHover aren't so absolute.

Here's the drama:

```
<style>
div#mrOverAbsolute
{
  z-index:1;
  /* ... and some other stuff */
}
div#mrAbsolute
{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  /* ... and some other stuff */
}
a.mrHover
{
  background:url('mrImage') 0 0;
}
a.mrHover:hover
{
  background-position:0 25;
}
</style>

<div id="mrOverAbsolute"></div>
<div id="mrAbsolute">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="" class="mrHover"></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Okay okay -- friends aside -- if I remove "position:absolute;", the sprite works. Otherwise, Chrome ignores the fact that I've declared a ":hover" in CSS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ask your friends to be reasonable or post the question in a reasonable form

Comment: First of all, remove the `<script>` elements as you're including CSS - include it within a `<style>` element instead .. you also need to include a position (relative, fixed/absolute) if you want to use `z-index`

Comment: Missing a quote after `class="mrHover`. I don't think this is causing your problem, but it can't help.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with the issue

Comment: My bad. They're actually included from a separate stylesheet. Like I said, everything works -- but my question is about letting :hover work from within an absolutely positioned element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no problem with `:hover` on absolutely positioned elements.

The problem is that you place the `#mrAbsolute` element behind the `#mrOverAbsolute` when you set its `z-index:-1` so the mouse events are intercepted by `#mrOverAbsolute`.